# How to construct a class from procedures with different signatures

Tags: c#

Consider the following class structure.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Company EmployeeCompany { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm constructing the Company class, I use the following SQL query (stored procedure) passed into the following constructor.

```
SELECT  CompanyId ,
        Name
FROM    dbo.Companies

private Company BuildCompany(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    return new Company()
    {
        CompanyId = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["CompanyId"]),
        Name = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["Name"])
    };
}
```

I use the following SQL query (stored procedure) to get the User information.

```
SELECT  EmployeeId ,
        e.Name AS EmployeeName ,
        c.CompanyId ,
        c.Name AS CompanyName
FROM    dbo.Employees AS e
        JOIN dbo.Companies AS c ON e.CompanyId = c.CompanyId
```

I use aliases to differentiate between the two Name columns. Now I need to construct a User class using this query. I'd like to maximize re-usability so I was trying to reuse the existing Company constructor, but with the different column names being returned, it obviously doesn't work.

So should I create a new constructor that just handles the aliased columns? Should I simply initialize a new Company object in the User constructor and map the properties directly? Is there a third option that would be more scalable and re-usable?

Comment: How about using an ORM (Object Relational Mapper), like Entity Framework?

Comment: If you're set on using this approach then I don't see a problem with just duplicating those lines of code in the `User` constructor.  The code is referencing different columns from a different database-generated result object, so it's reasonable that it doesn't use the same code.

Comment: @dotnetom I am not permitted to use an ORM. I'm working on convincing my boss but at this point they are not allowed.

Comment: @David I'm not dead set on this approach but I'm not able to use an ORM. Do you have a different approach you'd recommend?

Comment: @Lefka: A different approach I'd recommend would also be to use an ORM.  Failing that, if the requirement is to build the objects manually from stored procedure results then I don't really see the issue.  In one object you have a set of two columns, which you reference to build the object.  In another object you have a set of four columns, why not reference them to build that object?  Consistency is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is how you build a `Company`:

```
private Company BuildCompany(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    return new Company()
    {
        CompanyId = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["CompanyId"]),
        Name = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["Name"])
    };
}
```

And if this is the approach dictated by the technical requirements (as discussed in the comments on the question), then why not repeat the same pattern for building a `User`?

```
private User BuildUser(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    return new User()
    {
        Employee = new Employee()
        {
            EmployeeId = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["EmployeeId"]),
            CompanyId = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["CompanyId"]),
            Name = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["EmployeeName"])
        },
        Company = new Company()
        {
            CompanyId = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["CompanyId"]),
            Name = ConvertFromDbValue<string>(reader["CompanyName"])
        }
    };
}
```

It's not as pretty as, say, an ORM.  But it's consistent and supportable.  Any attempt to create a much more generic solution for the sole purpose of reducing keystrokes in the code will bring with it a bit of coupling.  It's up to you to decide if that coupling is worth the reduction of keystrokes.  In my experience, that's rare.

The SQL results are structurally very different and aren't really driven by the object model.  (For example, there's overlap between the `Employee` and `Company` objects in the `User` data results.)  This isn't a bad thing per se, as it does allow for further SQL-side optimization as the domain complexity increases.  But it does preclude generic approaches and instead lean toward manual approaches.  Again, not a bad thing per se.  But it's best to expose that explicitly in the code by maintaining the same manual patterns.

Unless there's a really compelling reason to introduce complexity, I'd err on the side of simplicity and refactor as needed.

Comment: To reduce wordiness, a well named set of extension methods on the SqlDataReader class could improve the flow to where this isn't bad if you can't use something more sophisticated.  Something that would end up like `reader.AsString("EmployeeID")` that wraps the `ConvertFromDbValue<T>` call, depending on where that method lives.